# Compare two wchar arrays within nested for loops?

Tags: c++, arrays, compare, wchar

hope someone can help me figure this out 
i´m kind of new to C++ and programing..

I have 2 different arrays first one is Alphabet from a-z
second is a integer array filled with virtual keycodes representing a-z.

the functions takes in a const wchar* as parameter that goes in to a stringstream 
and from there in to an array called buffer and then trying to compare Buffer[0] with Letter[0] if equal then simulate keypress with one of the keycodes, then compare next letter from string and keep going..
I cant se why this is not working haha.

Could there be a easier solution?

```
    unsigned short KeyCodes[26] = { 0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x46,0x47,0x48,0x49,0x4A,0x4B,0x4C,0x4D,0x4E,0x4F,0x50,0x51,0x52,0x53,0x54,0x55,0x56,0x57,0x58,0x59,0x5A };
wchar_t Letter[27] = L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

void WriteSimulator(const wchar_t* String)
{
    wchar_t Buffer[256];
    ss << String;
    ss >> Buffer;

    for (int a = 0; a < wcslen(Buffer); a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 27; b++)
        {
              /*Here is what i did wrong!
                Comparing as strings instead of just char.*/ 
            if (wcscmp(&Buffer[a], &Letter[b]) == 0)
            {
                KeyPress(KeyCodes[b], false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
//did write this from memory so it may be something missing...
```

```
//Solution!

void WriteSimulator(const wchar_t* String)
{
    wchar_t Buffer[256];
    ss << String;
    ss >> Buffer;

    for (int a = 0; a < wcslen(Buffer); a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < wcslen(Letter); b++)
        {
            if (Buffer[a] == Letter[b])
            {
                KeyPress(KeyCodes[b], false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have no definition in your code for the variable `ss`! But, assuming that's just a typo, then the ***real*** problem with your code is the line:

```
if (wcscmp(&Buffer[a], &Letter[b]) == 0)
```

where you are comparing the ***strings*** that start at `Buffer[a]` and `Letter[b]`.

To just compare the actual values of the **single characters** at each position, use:

```
if (Buffer[a] == Letter[b])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, ss is declared but just not visible here.. Comparing with the == operator solved my problem! I have already tried that in some way but must have done something else wrong that time, as a remember someone ones told me that you could not compare characters that way! Thanks! +rep